# TensorFlow Master and Worker Service

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the exact roles of the master and worker service in TensorFlow.

So far I understand that each TensorFlow task that I start is associated with a `tf.train.Server` instance. This instance exports a "master service" and "worker service" by implementing the [`tensorflow::Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#class-tensorflow-session) interface" (master) and [`worker_service.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/core/protobuf/worker_service.proto) (worker).

**1st Question: Am I right that this means, that ONE task is only associated with ONE worker?**

---

*Furthermore, I understood...*

*...about the Master:*
It is the scope of the master service...

(1) ...to offer functions to the client so that the client can run a session for example.

(2) ...to delegate work to the available workers in order to compute a session run.

**2nd Question:
In case we execute a graph distributed using more than one task, does only one master service get used?**

**3rd Question:
Should tf.Session.run get only called once?**

This is at least how I interpret this figure from [the whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf):

[image]

---

*... about the Worker:*
It is the scope of the worker service...

(1) to execute the nodes (which got delegated to him by the master service) on the devices the worker manages.

**4th Question:
How does one worker make use of multiple devices? Does a worker decide automatically how to distribute single operations?**

---

Please also correct me in case I came up with wrong statements!
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: for part 4, in earlier versions it would round-robin across GPU devices, in later versions it seems to put everything on GPU:0, so you need manual placement for multi-GPU configs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1st Question: Am I right that this means, that ONE task is only
>   associated with ONE worker?

This is the typical configuration, yes. Each [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Server) instance contains a full TensorFlow runtime, and the default configuration assumes that this runtime has exclusive access to the machine (in terms of how much memory it allocates on GPUs, etc.).

Note that you can create multiple [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Server) instances in the same process (and we sometimes do this [for testing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/server_lib_test.py)). However, there is little resource isolation between these instances, so running multiple instances in a single task is unlikely to yield good performance (with the current version).

> 2nd Question: In case we execute a graph distributed using more than
>   one task, does only one master service get used?

It depends on the [form of replication](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html#replicated-training) you are using. If you use "in-graph replication", you can use a single master service that knows about all replicas of the model (i.e. worker tasks). If you use "between-graph replication", you would use multiple master services, each of which knows about a single replica of the model, and is typically colocated with the worker task on which it runs. In general, we have found it more performant to use between-graph replication, and the [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Supervisor) library is designed to simplify operation in this mode.

> 3rd Question: Should [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) get only called once?

(I'm assuming this means "once per training step". A simple TensorFlow program for training a model will call `tf.Session.run()` in a loop.)

This depends on the form of replication you are using, **and** the coordination you want between training updates.

- Using **in-graph** replication, you can make **synchronous** updates by aggregating the losses or gradients in a single [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer), which gives a single `train_op` to run. In this case, you only call `tf.Session.run(train_op)` once per training step.
- Using **in-graph** replication, you make **asynchronous** updates by defining one `tf.train.Optimizer` per replica, which gives multiple `train_op` operations to run. In this case, you typically call each `tf.Session.run(train_op[i])` from a different thread, concurrently.
- Using **between-graph** replication, you make **synchronous** updates using the [`tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27eeb441bad8bcaa1bcba42a4b4ee49fb50ea0d3/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py), which is constructed separately in each replica. Each replica has its own training loop that  makes a single call to `tf.Session.run(train_op)`, and the `SyncReplicasOptimizer` coordinates these so that the updates are applied synchronously (by a background thread in one of the workers).
- Using **between-graph** replication, you make **asynchronous** updates by using another `tf.train.Optimizer` subclass (other than `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`), using a training loop that similar to the synchronous case, but without the background coordination.

> 4th Question: How does one worker make use of multiple devices? Does a
>   worker decide automatically how to distribute single operations or...?

Each worker runs the same placement algorithm that is used in single-process TensorFlow. Unless instructed otherwise, the placer will put operations on the GPU if one is available (and there is a GPU-accelerated implementation), otherwise it will fall back to the CPU. The [`tf.train.replica_device_setter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#replica_device_setter) device function can be used to shard variables across tasks that act as "parameter servers". If you have more complex requirements (e.g. multiple GPUs, local variables on the workers, etc.) you can use explicit [`with tf.device(...):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#device) blocks to assign subgraphs to a particular device.